# How to set button disabled for 24 hours after some clicks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have set a button click for some background API service to execute and after 3 clicks,I want the button to be disabled and only enabled after 24 hours.I did the following code but it is failed to be disabled.Here...

```
   companion object {

    var clickCount = 0
    const val SAVED_TIME  = "Time is saved"
     }


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val convert: Button = findViewById(R.id.Cbutton)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    inputAmount = findViewById(R.id.editText)
    inputAmount!!.textSize = 30f
    spin = findViewById(R.id.spin)
    birr = findViewById(R.id.converted)
    birr!!.text = getString(R.string.initialValue)
    progressIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)


    statusBarColorChange()
    connectionStatusUpdate()
    currencyListAdapterExecute()
    convert.setOnClickListener {

        val sharedPrefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TIME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        if (inputAmount!!.text.isNotEmpty() && connected) {

            val dateNow = Date().time
            val savedDateTime = sharedPrefs.getLong("time",0)

            if(savedDateTime == dateNow){
                convert.isEnabled = false
            }

            clickCount += 1

            if(clickCount < 4){

                FetchedJsonData(this).execute()
            }

            else {
                val exactTime = Date().time
                sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("time",exactTime).apply()
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store time in shared preference by following code.

```
SharedPreferences  settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 1);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("click_time", your_time);
```

Whenever need to compare, just compare your current time with the time stored in preference. Check if difference between time is less than 24 hours or not.

TO get time from prefernce:

```
SharedPreferences  settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 1);
   String storedTime=settings.getString("clic_time", "");
```

Get difference in hours:

```
Date current, Date previous;
   long diff = current.getTime() - previous.getTime();
   long hours= diff / (60*60 * 1000);
```

To show timer, when app comes from background, you can get time from preference and start timer by using difference between 2 times.

Comment: I have made a change.The problem is after I closed the app and return,the buttons are still active.

Comment: val savedDateTime = sharedPrefs.getLong("time",0)
        val dateDifference  = Date().time - savedDateTime
        val hours = dateDifference / 1000 * 60 * 60

        if(hours < 24.0){

            convert.isEnabled = false
        }

Comment: have you checked what is the value of hours here?

Comment: If the difference between the two dates are less than 24 hours,the button must be disabled,i think.

Comment: Yes and this is the requirement as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168509/discussion-between-haileapp-and-raman-sharma).